# How to load nested data with Graphql from storyblok?

Tags: graphql, gridsome, headless-cms, storyblok

I'm trying to fetch with one graphql query all needed information for a blog post. I'm using [gridsome](https://gridsome.org/) and [storyblok](https://storyblok.com). For that, I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/storyblok/gridsome-source-storyblok#readme).

The first query loads with the ID everything from a specific blog post but is not loading nested data like categories or authors.

For example:

```
<page-query>
    query StoryblokEntry ($id: ID) {
        storyblokEntry (id: $id) {
            id
            slug
            content
        }
    }
</page-query>
```

When I test the query with the ID of "story-3850216-default", I get this result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "storyblokEntry": {
      "id": "story-3850216-default",
      "slug": "hello-world",
      "content": {
        "_uid": "f5a0bd9d-ec13-4381-ae5f-a7e2bb093fbe",
        "title": "Hello World ",
        "authors": [
          "61dec800-1b17-443e-961a-1cf8ef08d803"
        ],
        "content": "hi",
        "component": "article-post",
        "categories": [
          "e1509e6e-2007-4d4b-8857-4bc1105c5505"
        ],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do, so that the values of authors and categories are eager loaded?

My background is coming from normal REST-APIs and now I'm a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Storyblok has components as first class citizens resolving a attribute can be done via the resolve_relations api function. This lets you also resolve attributes in deeply nested components just by providing the component name and the attribute (YOUR_COMPONENT.YOUR_ATTRIBUTE).

```
{
  use: 'gridsome-source-storyblok',
  options: {
    ...
    params: {
      resolve_relations: 'article-post.authors,article-post.categories'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That was helpful. One side question. How could you shrink the result? Currently it results into many data that I don't need to know, like `uuid`, `parent_id` etc. I'm actually only interested of the content of authors.

Comment: another problem that arrives is when you use the visual editor, that the nested data are not loaded! One way is just to add `resolve_relations` in the `window.storyblok.get` method of the editor. but this feels super sloppy.